# Swift change label text background color according to plist file

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a plist file and I have a detail view that reads the plist file and gets information pretty well,
I would like to know how I can check if a plist item has a certain value and if it does it will change the value to the according color.

Heres my code so far. it doesn't work anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
//
//  DetailViewController.swift
//  ConversationalCards
//
//  Created by Avi Tannenbaum on 3/20/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Avi Tannenbaum. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var modeLabel: UILabel!

    var card: Card?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let card = card {
            navigationItem.title = card.name?.capitalizedString
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: card.name!.lowercaseString)
            titleLabel.text = card.title?.capitalizedString

            //Mode label
            modeLabel.text = card.mode?.capitalizedString
            // Color the text backgrounds and then resize them later for the cards
            //Red

            if ((card.color? = "none") != nil) {
                titleLabel.hidden = false
            }

            if ((card.color? = "0") != nil) {
                titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            }
            //Green
            else if ((card.color? = "1") != nil) {
             titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            }
            // Yellow
            else if ((card.color? = "2") != nil) {
              titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            }
            // Blue
            else if ((card.color? = "3") != nil) {
              titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            }

            // lIght green
            else if ((card.color? = "4") != nil) {
               titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 238.0, green: 204, blue: 204.0, alpha: 1.0)

            }
            // darkred Hex code: #C84D59
            else if ((card.color? = "5") != nil) {
              titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 238.0, green: 204.0, blue: 204.0, alpha: 10)
            }
            else if ((card.color? = "6") != nil) {
                titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 104.0, green: 88.0, blue: 139.0, alpha: 1.0)
            }
           // Label style
           // self.titleLabelStyle() 
        } 
    }

    /* not working yet this is the function responseble for converting hex values to UIColor values - Avi Tannenbaum
    extension UIColor {
        public convenience init?(hexString: String) {
            let r, g, b, a: CGFloat

            if hexString.hasPrefix("#") {
                let start = hexString.startIndex.advancedBy(1)
                let hexColor = hexString.substringFromIndex(start)

                if hexColor.characters.count == 8 {
                    let scanner = NSScanner(string: hexColor)
                    var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0
                    if scanner.scanHexLongLong(&hexNumber) {
                        r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
                        g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0X00FF0000) >> 16) / 255
                        b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
                        a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255

                        self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
            return nil
        }

    } */


    // Style functions
    /*
    func titleLabelStyle() {
        let title = self.titleLabel
        title.numberOfLines = 0
        title.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 300, height: title.intrinsicContentSize().height)
    }
 */
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

heres the plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
 "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Begin</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string> </string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string> </string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>none</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Getting Started</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>THE COMPLIMENT
            I WANT TO GIVE YOU...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>WARM UP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date One</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>TALK ABOUT YOUR NEXT VACATION...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date One</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I THINK OUR BEST MEMORY IS...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date One</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>AN ADVENTURE I WANT TO SHARE WITH YOU...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date One</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I TRUST YOU BECAUSE...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date One</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I FELL IN LOVE WITH YOU WHEN...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date One</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>RECEIVE A HUG...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>TRY THIS</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date One</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I REALLY APPRECIATE WHEN YOU...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>WARM UP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Two</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>You MAKE ME REALLY HAPPY WHEN...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Two</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I BELIEVE IN YOU BECAUSE...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Two</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>SOMETHING SILLY l WANT TO DO WITH YOU...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Two</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I WANT TO PAMPER YOU BY...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Two</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>A SMALL DOSE OF ROMANCE WOULD INCLUDE...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Two</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>HOLD HANDS WITH EYES CLOSED...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>TRY THIS</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Two</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>A GIFT I WOULD LIKE TO RECEIVE FROM YOU...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>WARM UP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Three</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>ONE THING I HAVE LEARNED FROM YOU...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Three</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I WANT TO SHOW YOU SUPPORT BY...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Three</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>WHAT IS YOUR FAVOURITE ROMANTIC MOVIE? WHY?</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Three</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>MY ATTRACTION TO YOU DEEPENED WHEN...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Three</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I Think OUR RELATIONSHIP IS AT ITS BEST WHEN...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Three</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>WRITE YOUR PARTNER A THANKYOU NOTE...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>TRY THIS</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Four</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I WAS FIRST ATTRACTED TO YOU BECAUSE...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>WARM UP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Four</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>You BRING OUT THE BEST IN ME BY...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Four</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I&apos;D LIKE TO STUDY _ WITH YOU.</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Four</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>SOMETHING CRAZY I WANT TO DO WITH YOU...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Four</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>ONE WAY TO TREAT OURSELVES TOGETHER...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Four</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I THINK OF US WHEN l HEAR THIS SONG...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Four</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>RECEIVE A HEAD MASSAGE.</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>TRY THIS</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>3</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Five</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>MY EARLIEST MEMORY OF OUR FRIENDSHIP...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>WARM UP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>4</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Five</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>SOMETHING EXCITING WE CAN DO TOGETHER...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>4</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Five</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>OUR IDEAL DAY TOGETHER...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>4</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Five</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>IF I COULD BUY YOU ANYTHING I WOULD BUY YOU...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>4</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Five</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I FEEL CLOSE TO YOU WHEN...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>4</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Five</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>DESCRIBE A ROMANTIC EVENING</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>4</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Five</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>WRITE YOUR PARTNER A COMPLIMENT NOTE.</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>TRY THIS</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>4</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Five</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>THE TALENT OF YOURS I REALLY LIKE...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>WARM UP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>5</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date SIx</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I ADMIRE THA T YOU...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>5</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date SIx</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I WANT TO THANK YOU FOR...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>5</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date SIx</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>A SURPRISE I&apos;D LIKE FROM YOU...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>5</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date SIx</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I LOVE YOU BECAUSE...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>5</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date SIx</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>MY EARLIEST MEMORY OF OUR ROMANCE...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>5</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date SIx</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>RECEIVE A SHOULDER MASSAGE</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>TRY THIS</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>5</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date SIx</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>ONE OF YOUR STRENGTHS...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>WARM UP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>6</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Seven</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>ONE PLEASURE I WOULD LIKE TO GIVE YOU...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>ENCOURAGING EACH OTHER</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>6</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Seven</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>OUR LOVE REMINDS ME OF THIS CANDY...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>STRENGTHENING YOUR RELATIONSHIP</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>6</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Seven</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I FEEL SAFE WITH YOU BECAUSE...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>A LITTLE BIT OF FUN</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>6</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Seven</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I WANT YOU TO PAMPER ME BY...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>DEEPENING YOUR BOND</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>6</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Seven</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>I THINK YOU ARE SEXY BECAUSE...</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>FUEL YOUR ROMANCE</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>6</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Seven</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Card</string>
        <key>title</key>
        <string>LOOK INTO EACH OTHERS EYES.</string>
        <key>mode</key>
        <string>TRY THIS</string>
        <key>color</key>
        <string>6</string>
        <key>group</key>
        <string>Date Seven</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist> "
```

what im trying to do is to set the label background to the the color mentioned in the relevant plist.

Comment: It might be helpful to show how you translate the property list into Card types. Perhaps something is getting lost there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upvoting the other answer because I didn't notice that you're not doing a comparison in your if's. But also wanted to add that you might want to consider a switch statement here instead of a series of if/else statements. For example your `viewDidLoad` could be written as:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let card = card {
        navigationItem.title = card.name?.capitalizedString
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: card.name!.lowercaseString)
        titleLabel.text = card.title?.capitalizedString

        //Mode label
        modeLabel.text = card.mode?.capitalizedString

        // Color the text backgrounds and then resize them later for the cards
        //Red

        switch card.color ?? "none" {   // default to none
            case "0":    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            case "1":    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            case "2":    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
            case "3":    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            case "4":    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 238.0, green: 204, blue: 204.0, alpha: 1.0)
            case "5":    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 238.0, green: 204.0, blue: 204.0, alpha: 1.0)
            case "6":    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 104.0, green: 88.0, blue: 139.0, alpha: 1.0)
            default:     titleLabel.hidden = false
        }

        // Label style
        // self.titleLabelStyle()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change `if ((card.color? = "none") != nil) {}`

to this:

```
if let colorString = card.color{
    if colorString == "none" {

    }
}
```

hope it helpful :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. You have used "=", which is setting your object value rather than checking it. You need to use "==".
2. The != nil parts are unnecessary

Comment: Thanks guys it really helped